# Dual installation with Wubi

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi

I have tried installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 with the Wubi Windows installer.  Now at startup when I click on Ubuntu (as opposed to  Windows) I get the following message:

```
Windows Boot Manager
file:  \ubuntu\winboot\wubilder.mbr
Status:  OxcOOOOO7b
Info:  the applicationor operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
```

I have tried installing Ubuntu 3 times and get the same message each time.  What do I do from here?

Comment: Wubi doesn't work on computers that ship with Windows 8 (or any computer that boots with `UEFI` i.e. `GPT` disks.